# ConstraintLayout cannot preview

Tags: android

ConstraintLayout cannot preview.
My Android Studio version is 4.1.1.
ConstraintLayout version is 2.0.4.
Here is my xml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/red" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error message is as follows：

```html
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/appcompat/R$styleable
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.themifyContext(AppCompatViewInflater.java:360)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor500.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:328)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:373)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:713)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:844)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F02lq.png)

Answer (score 1):

A simple **Build --> Clean Project** then **Invalidate Caches and Restart** and finally **Sync gradle** should help.

Comment: Speechless. I tried many times before, but it didn't work. This time, it did!

Comment: It works after cleaning, but it dosn't work after running again! What's the problem?